# Force commit / push of file

Tags: git, version-control

There is a file in the repository (git) that appears to be the wrong image; however it shares the names of the correct image.

Not sure how the wrong image got in place, but in my local copy I have the correct image of the same name, but when I try to commit this file doesn't show up in the lost of files that have changed.

How can I force a commit (or push) of that file so the repository has the correct image?

Comment: So it committed locally but doesn't push?

Comment: Ummm.... no, it doesn't even show up as needing to be committed, because it hasn't changed locally I guess. But I don't know how to force push it I guess?

Comment: Unless something ends up on your index, there's nothing for git to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may be on a wrong branch. Git status **will** show changed content - no matter what the name or if it's a binary file.

Comment: how do you inspect the image that's "in the repository"?

Comment: That's a good question, they are supposed to be auto-uploaded to a test server, but that is showing the incorrect image - so perhaps that's just wrong haha

Comment: See what that server has checked out. It's most likely on a different commit.